# how to programmatically add an image to a activity android

Tags: android, image, imageview, coordinates

Hi I am trying to programatically add an image to an activity for an android app

I have this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
           (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);

        try {
            Class res = R.drawable.class;
            Field field = res.getField(device_types.get(i));
            int resId = field.getInt(null);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(resId);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
        }

        LinearLayout link_devices = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.link_devices);
        link_devices.addView(imageView);
```

however it doesnt let me get the location of the images  ( i try and get 0 for getTop, getLeft etc..)

am i doing it wrong and was is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting image on that imageview, and you have set WRAP_CONTENT as layout params, which means the size of the imageView is same as size of image you are setting on it.
Since no image is attached the imageView size is 0.

Try setting an image, using any one of the codes ;- imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm), setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) or setImageResource(int ResID).

I don't get what you're doing the with this code & its not required:

```
Class res = R.drawable.class;
Field field = res.getField(device_types.get(i));
int resId = field.getInt(null);
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(resId);
```

Comment: that code basically allows me to convert the context of my string to the resId of the image so i am essentially using setImageResource --> could you please explain what code from the top you think needs cutting out

Comment: easiest is setImageResource(int ResId).
If you have an image in res/drawable folder with name x.png, you can set image by
"imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);"

Comment: i changed the code to http://fixee.org/paste/lg2zs9o/ but the Syst.out.prinltlns still give me 0

Comment: you will always get the size value of imageView as 0, until it is drawn on the screen  & you are trying to get the values before it is measured.

Comment: what do i need to change if i want to get the coordinates of the shape once on screen

Comment: taking what you said into account i moved the code so im checking it after i added it to the screen but still getting the error http://fixee.org/paste/lg2zs9o/#url=34fo6da

Comment: i want to explain 2 things here:
getLeft() & getTop can be zero, because imageview will be placed in left top corner, where left & top is always zero. Check getRight() & getBottom().
second case: Measurement is a background process,so before measuring the view,if getLeft() call is executed you wont get size0 .To avoid such conditions sometimes we use imageView.post(Runnable r) method, which will be executed only after measuring process.